# Lineでオウム返しBotを作りたいのに返ってこない

Tags: google-apps-script, line

参考サイト
https://gurishunin.com/line_gas_beginner/

初心者です。
上記のサイト様のコードをコピペし、アクセストークンのところにチャネルアクセストークン(長期)を入れました。
webnock設定もしてあり、URLも張りました(検証を押すと成功と表示されます)。
しかし、試しに友達登録してからメッセージを送ってもオウム返ししてくれません。
何が原因なのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

[上記サイト様のソースコード]

```
// LINE developersのメッセージ送受信設定に記載のアクセストークン
const ACCESS_TOKEN = '長期アクセストークン';
function doPost(e) {
// WebHookで受信した応答用Token
var replyToken = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0].replyToken;
// ユーザーのメッセージを取得
var userMessage = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0].message.text;
// 応答メッセージ用のAPI URL
var url = 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply';
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
'headers': {
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
},
'method': 'post',
'payload': JSON.stringify({
'replyToken': replyToken,
'messages': [{
'type': 'text',
'text': userMessage,
}],
}),
});
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'content': 'post ok'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

[設定]
webhook→on
応答メッセージ→無効
あいさつメッセージ→有効
webhookの利用→on

Comment: 例えばこんな記事の手法を応用してログを採取して解析してみてはどうでしょう？ [GoogleAppsScriptの実行ログをスプレッドシートに出力する方法](https://lusknote.com/617)

Answer (score 0):

無事にログを確認したところ、エラーが出ていることが判明しました！

GCPを使用したログの確認方法
https://qiita.com/sa9ra4ma/items/1acb459fcc713728c03e

新しく質問させていただきます！
ありがとうございました！